# Using nosetests in PyCharm having python 2 and 3 installed side by side

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm, nose, nosetests

I am trying to use nosetest with python 2 and 3 isntalled side by side in PyCharm (2.7.3).

Everything works fine under python 2.7, but any test in python 3.4 fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robert/Programme/pycharm-2.7.3/helpers/pycharm/noserunner.py", line 91, in <module>
    process_args()
  File "/home/robert/Programme/pycharm-2.7.3/helpers/pycharm/noserunner.py", line 88, in process_args
    TestProgram(argv=argv, config=config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/core.py", line 121, in __init__
    **extra_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/main.py", line 93, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/core.py", line 207, in runTests
    result = self.testRunner.run(self.test)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/core.py", line 62, in run
    test(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/suite.py", line 177, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/suite.py", line 224, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/suite.py", line 177, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/suite.py", line 224, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 46, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kwarg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 139, in run
    result.addError(self, err)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/proxy.py", line 131, in addError
    plugins.addError(self.test, err)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 99, in __call__
    return self.call(*arg, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 167, in simple
    result = meth(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/robert/Programme/pycharm-2.7.3/helpers/pycharm/nose_utils.py", line 51, in addError
    err = self.formatErr(err)
  File "/home/robert/Programme/pycharm-2.7.3/helpers/pycharm/nose_utils.py", line 58, in formatErr
    return ''.join(traceback.format_exception(exctype, value, tb))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/traceback.py", line 181, in format_exception
    return list(_format_exception_iter(etype, value, tb, limit, chain))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/traceback.py", line 146, in _format_exception_iter
    for value, tb in values:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/traceback.py", line 125, in _iter_chain
    context = exc.__context__
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__context__'
```

Moreover in the run configuration of the nosetest run for the python 3 interpreter it says:

```
WARNING: No nosetest runner found in selected interpreter
```

What do I have to do in order to fix this? How do I choose an appropriate runner for python 3 nosetests in pyCharm (2.7.3) ? Thanks!

EDIT: Btw, it's pyCharm 2.7.3

Comment: Does the error go away if you change `return ''.join(traceback.format_exception(exctype, value, tb))` to `return ''.join(traceback.format_exception(exctype, value, tb, chain=False))` in `/home/robert/Programme/pycharm-2.7.3/helpers/pycharm/nose_utils.py`, line 58?

Comment: Yes, thanks, that worked. Do you want to post this as a real answer instead of a comment, so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: Hmm the problem is now, that I don't have a traceback any more. So debugging becomes a nightmare, is there a workaround?

Comment: And, furthermore, using the keyword argument ``chain=False`` does not work under python 2.7.3 and tests do not start. But I want to use both at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, to post my workaround here to make it easier to find for others. Replacing line 58 in `PathToPyCharm/pycharm-2.7.3/helpers/pycharm/nose_utils.py` with

```
if sys.version_info[0]==3:
    return ''.join(traceback.format_exception(exctype, value, tb, chain=False))
else:
    return ''.join(traceback.format_exception(exctype, value, tb))
```

made `nosetests` work with python 3.4 and 2.7. Yet, using python 3.4 the entire stack-trace is lost if an error occurs. As a consequence, debugging becomes a nightmare :(

Finally, I solved the problem simply by upgrading my PyCharm version to 3.4.1.

Comment: This workaround is still valid with pycharm 4.0.3 and python 3.4.2.

Comment: In pycharm 4.5 this is still a problem but now it's line 70 you need to change.

Comment: Still a problem here on 4.5.4, still works on line 70.

Comment: I still have this problem with PyCharm 5.0.4.

Comment: I have this with 5.04 too! I'm not keen on the idea of modifying Pycharm's code to make things work!

Comment: still valid with pycharm 2016.3 - i hope they fix this.